# How to access input json variable in Camunda Script Task?

Tags: groovy, camunda, camunda-modeler

I would like to call (through Postman) a Camunda model with a json input and i would like to use it in a Script Task.
Also, i would like to modify the response json file.

Hello,

When i call a Camunda model with a json input, i would like to use it in a Script Task, but i can't figure out how access it.

When i build up the json in the script like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def str = '{"id":"12345678","name":"Sharon"}'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)

println slurper.name
```

It works, but if i call it from Postman with this:

```
{
    "id2" : "12345678"
}
```

From the documentation it's seems simple like this:
Print id2

But in the response i get this error: "No such property: id2 for class: Script4"

Any suggestion?
Also, can i somehow modify the response json?

Comment: Show reference to documentation, show your code that doesn't work, show API that you're calling...

Comment: I tried to use this documentation: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/concepts/expressions/#access-variables

In the "script task" -  "inline script/script" i put this:
print("js run")
print(id);

i call it with postman, where i put in the body this:
{
    "id" : "12345678"
}

I see in the console the js run part, but the second one drops an error:
"ReferenceError: id is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,
POST request body:

```
{   "variables": 
        {   
            "Request": {
                    "value": {"Application": {
                                    "id":"12345678",
                                    "Applicant" : {
                                        "BirthDate" : "2022-01-01"
                                    }
                                }}
            }
        },
            "withVariablesInReturn": true
}
```

In the script task now i can use the request:

```
print(Request.Application.id);
```

As far as i understood you have to add the request to the variables.
The withVariablesInReturn return variables in the response.